# I need to split txts around 100-250MB in parts of 25MB

Tags: powershell

I need to split a lot files, in others with less size. Because when the server read bigfiles, the CPU takes the 100% of usage and I only can accept the maximum charge of 70%. So I think it will be perfect if I can split them in files around 25 MB.

Example of file:

```
07/11/2018 loginfo B4 45 FR.txt -- 100MB
```

Result that I want:

```
1 07/11/2018 loginfo B4 45 FR.txt -- 25MB
2 07/11/2018 loginfo B4 45 FR.txt -- 25MB
3 07/11/2018 loginfo B4 45 FR.txt -- 25MB
4 07/11/2018 loginfo B4 45 FR.txt -- 25MB
```

Another thing to keep in mind is control the files less than 25MB.

Comment: The is an XY problem. Likely the issue is how you are reading the files in the first place. Use something like a `streamreader` so you are not loading the whole file in memory (guessing you are using `get-content`)

Comment: Which application is processing that file on your server? If that is powershell script you probably don't need to split it, since you can load it line by line

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Note the -ReadCount 512 bit meas it will process 512 lines at a time.

```
$FromPath = "C:\LOGS\LOG.txt"
$ToPath = "C:\LOGS"

$From = Get-Content -Path $FromPath -ReadCount 512

$SplitN = 1
$N = 0

while ($N -lt $From.Count) {
    $IT = New-Item "$ToPath\Logout $SplitN.txt"
        while ($(Get-Item -Path $IT.FullName).Length -lt 25mb -and ($N -lt $From.Count)){
            Add-Content -Path $IT.FullName -Value $From[$N]  #$From[$N]
            $N++
        }
    $SplitN++
}
```